# Android - Path not rotating with Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I have the following code to try to rotate a path:

```
//inside onDraw
switch (orientation) {
    case FACE_FRONT:
        canvas.save();
        updatePath();
        canvas.rotate(0);
        canvas.restore();
        break;
    case FACE_RIGHT:
        canvas.save();
        updatePath();
        canvas.rotate(90);
        canvas.restore();
        break;
    case FACE_REAR:
        canvas.save();
        updatePath();
        canvas.rotate(180);
        canvas.restore();
        break;
    case FACE_LEFT:
        canvas.save();
        updatePath();
        canvas.rotate(270);
        canvas.restore();
        break;
    }

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

public void updatePath() {
    if (mPointArray.size() > 1) {
        mPath.moveTo(mPointArray.get(0).x * scaleX, mPointArray.get(0).y * scaleX);
        for (int x = 1; x < mPointArray.size(); x++) {
            mPath.lineTo(mPointArray.get(x).x * scaleX, mPointArray.get(x).y * scaleX);
        }
    }
    mPath.offset((centerX - (tmWidth / 2)) * -scaleX, (centerY - (tmWidth / 2)) * -scaleX);
}
```

For some unknown reason my Path isn't rotating with the Canvas.  Could anyone let me know what am I doing wrong.

I tried looking for other examples, but most of the examples seem to be with Bitmaps instead of Paths.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call restore()?

Remove all canvas.save() and canvas.restore() calls and you will be fine.

So your code inside onDraw() should be something like this:

```
    updatePath();
    switch (orientation) {
        case FACE_FRONT:
            canvas.rotate(0);
            break;
        case FACE_RIGHT:
            canvas.rotate(90);
            break;
        case FACE_REAR:
            canvas.rotate(180);
            break;
        case FACE_LEFT:
            canvas.rotate(270);
            break;
    }
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
```